# How can I load a file which includes text and numeric data?

Tags: file-io, logo-lang

How can I load a *.csv file which includes text and numerical data in LOGO?

e.g. N 43.876 W

Comment: Yeah, but adding LOGO was a bit too much, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is SO I assume you're meaning within code.

Basically you're reading in a line, and parsing it (looking for commas, spaces, pipes, whatever you use to delimit), and doing a split (most languages support this in their string libraries) to get an array of your values.  If you know which value should be an int then you convert it.

If you mean so you can look at it yourself - use notepad, wordpad, word, excel, openoffice, pspad, vim, pico, whatever you want.

EDIT:  Now that you've included more info - [This resource](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/v2ch2/diff.html) includes file reading and extracting information from files in LOGO.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some very basic File IO code using LOGO.

I used [FMSLogo](http://www.fmslogo.org) on Windows.

Assuming the file **test.csv** is in the same directory as the fmslogo binary

```
OPENREAD "test.csv
SETREAD "test.csv
SHOW READLIST
```

The key part here is **SHOW READLIST** which prints out the contents of the current line and the moves the file pointer to the next line.